# The DOF of $S^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

As we know ，if $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ are samples ,the sample average is:$$\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$$
and the sample variance is $$S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(\bar{X}-X_i)^2$$
my textbook point out that the denominator $n-1$ is degrees of freedom(DOF).

The book gives three explains of why the DOF should be $n-1$ ,one of the explain confused me,it said:

> To substitute $\bar{X}$ into $\sum_{i=1}^n(\bar{X}-X_i)^2$,we can get a 
>   quadric form $\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}X_iX_j\quad(a_{ij}=a_{ji})$,the rank of matrix A($a_{ij}$) is $n-1$

I tried to do some calculation 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n(\bar{X}-X_i)^2&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(nX_i-\sum_{j=1}^nX_j)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(nX_i-s)^2\quad (s=\sum_{j=1}^nX_j)\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(n^2X_i^2+s^2-2nsX_i)\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}(n^2\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2+ns^2-2ns\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-\frac{s^2}{n}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(n-1)X_i^2-\sum_{i\neq j}X_iX_j\right)
\end{align*}
and then it seems like we ought to get the rank of $A$ $$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
n-1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1\\
-1 & n-1 & -1 & \cdots & -1\\
-1 & -1 & n-1 & \cdots & -1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
-1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & n-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but eventually I failed，how to calculate the rank？I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some advice.

Comment: I am not fond of degrees of freedom arguments. The real reason (I think) is that with $n-1$ we get an unbiased estimator of the variance. Sounds good, although there is reason to think that the biased estimator with $n$ instead of $n-1$ is "better."

Answer (score 0):

The approach looks correct. Now to find the rank of $A$, the question to ask is:

**Hint**:

*Can any of the rows of $A$ be produced from a linear combination of any other rows?*

If **no**: the rank is $n$.

If **yes**: then you need to find out how many linearly independent row vectors exist in the space spanned by the row vectors. This can be done using a variety of ways, and a quick Google search reveals Gaussian elimination, reduction to row echelon form, etc.

Comment: If **no**, the rank is $n$ since $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix. My favorite way to deal with a matrix of this structure is by solving the eigenvalue problem. You can recognize that $A = nI - 1 1'$, and you can guess the eigenvectors from symmetry considerations.